# How to make a button consistent on all size of display?

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Image attached is the button from display of two different sizes (24inch and 13inch), button on 24inch display appears normal whereas add to cart button on 13inch display is broken.[13inch display button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK7Mv.jpg) [24 inch display button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiUdO.jpg)

```
    <div class="row my-5" id="3">
            <span id="lblArtworkId" style="display: none;">3</span>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <a href="./">
                        <img src="upload/artworks/Artwork3.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top" style="max-height: 8rem;">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                    <span>
                        <a href="./" class="text-decoration-none text-muted fs-4">
                            Construction in Red, Blue & Yellow Drawing
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="m-0">Artist: Karin White</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <span class="fw-bold">$ 1120.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <button id="btnRemove" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Remove</button>
                    <button id="btnCart" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Web browsers don't care about the size of the monitor. You should be thinking about the pixel width of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `col`s with a breakpoint prefix to adjust the layout. (e.g. `col-xxl-2 col-3`). Read [Bootstrap Breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/) and [Grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) for more information. Also, since Bootstrap is sensitive to pixels, it is much better to consider pixels instead of inches.

Example:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row my-5" id="3">
        <span id="lblArtworkId" style="display: none;">3</span>
        <div class="col-xxl-2 col-3">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a href="./">
                    <img src="upload/artworks/Artwork3.jpg" alt="" class="card-img-top" style="max-height: 8rem;">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xxl-6 col-9">
            <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                <span>
                    <a href="./" class="text-decoration-none text-muted fs-4">
                        Construction in Red, Blue & Yellow Drawing
                    </a>
                </span>
                <hr>
                <p class="m-0">Artist: Karin White</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xxl-2 col-4">
            <div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <span class="fw-bold">$ 1120.00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xxl-2 col-8">
            <div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <button id="btnRemove" class="btn btn-outline-danger w-50 mx-1">Remove</button>
                <button id="btnCart" class="btn btn-primary w-50 mx-1">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

Don't forget to include the [required meta tags](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template):

```
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
```

Comment: thank you sir for your comment, i had read thru the documentation, but both my 13inch and 24inch display are the same resolution which is 1920 x 1080p

Comment: So it looks like you did not use the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) meta tag. Is that right?

Comment: i see, thank you, i  have solved my problem